# Array JSON a forEach Javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel-8, javascript-objeto

Quiero que estos datos me aparezcan en un `forEach` pero me sale esto:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

no logro que iteren.

**Array:**

```
{
    "error": {
        "nombreCita": [
            "Su nombre es requerido."
        ],
        "apellidoCita": [
            "Su apellido es requerido."
        ],
        "emailCita": [
            "Su E-Mail es requerido."
        ],
        "fecha": [
            "The fecha field is required."
        ]
    }
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
datas.error.forEach((valor, index, datas) => {
    console.log('Index: ' + valor + ' Value: ' + datas[valor]);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu error está que `forEach()` se utiliza con los arrays y este es un objeto, te vendría mejor usar un `for(e in obj)`

```
const json = JSON.parse(`
{
    "error": {
        "nombreCita": [
            "Su nombre es requerido."
        ],
        "apellidoCita": [
            "Su apellido es requerido."
        ],
        "emailCita": [
            "Su E-Mail es requerido."
        ],
        "fecha": [
            "The fecha field is required."
        ]
    }
}
`)


for(m in json.error){
    console.log(m) //imprime cada clave (nombreCita..)
    console.log(json.error[m]) //imprime el valor 
    //aqui si podrías usar el foreach ya que es un arrat el valor, 
    //pero no es necesario ya que solo cuenta con 1 valor 
}
```

Comment: Excelente, lo probé y me funcionó... gracias...